# conditional formatting getting rid of cell color

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am making a floorpan of a building for an architecture company on excel with each cell representing a room. I have used conditional formatting to put polka dots inside a cell (which represents a room) if that room is finished and will say finished in green text. Otherwise, the cell remains blank and will state not finished in red text. This was easy to do. But the conditional formatting gets rid of the color I had painted the cell before using the conditional formatting. So my question is, is there anyway to keep the previous color (important because different types of room are color coded differently), while just adding polka dots to the room based on if its finished or not. Thanks let me know people. much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want the polka dots on top of the existing colour? Or do you want the original colour to come back if the condition doesn't apply any more? if you could link to images to clarify the current situation and the desired result, it would be helpful

Comment: yes add the polka dots on top of the existing colour. so i have a purple cell once that cell is finished, I would type finished in another sheet and conditional formatting would then add polka dots to the cell with purple color in it. (purple indicating the room type)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may have specified a color (even if it was No Color) for your conditional formatting when you added your polka dots.

If you open up your conditional format to the Fill tab and hit the Clear button on the bottom right, then reselect your polka dot pattern it should apply the dots without changing the underlying color. This is, of course, assuming you don't have any other conditional formats applying colors to those cells.